# Delete object from array of multiple objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array like:

```
var participants = [
  {username: "john", time: null}, 
  {username: "samira", time: null}, 
  {username: "mike", time: null}, 
  {username: "son", time:null}
]
```

I want to remove an item by username:

```
const index = participants.map(x => {

  x.map(y => {
      return y.username;
    })
  }).indexOf(username); //get index of username

participants.splice(index, 1);
```

Hence, index of username returns "-1", therefore participants array becomes 0?

Expected output, by username: 'son':

```
[
  {username: "john", time: null}, 
  {username: "samira", time: null}, 
  {username: "mike", time: null}
]
```

UPDATE:

Turns out my array is within an array, like this

[image: Console log array]

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: Use participants.filter() instead so you don't have to splice(). Your shown code does not work since x is already the item instead of an array you can map again. PS: there's a function called `array.findIndex()` as well if you ever need to do more than just filter out something.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Array filter function

`participants.filter((item) => item.username !== username))`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: What if the array was within another array, as question updated?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var username = 'son';

for(var i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
    if(participants[i].username == username) {
        participants.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

NOTE: `filter`, `map` and the like offer code readability while `for` loops are better performing. Choose according to your specific problem.

Comment: When using splice inside that kind of loop i remember to decrease i after splice, otherwise if there are two consecutive matching entries the second wont be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method or in your way with splice and map :

```
participants.splice(participants.map(x => x.username).indexOf(username),1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function, but filter doesn’t change the original array; so you have to reassign results to the original variable.
             participants = participants.filter((item) => item.username !== username))